# Joomla Frozen Menu Items

Tags: joomla, menu

On this site: http://67.15.245.6/~paddyosh/ the main navigation has suddenly stopped changing, i am sure i didn't change the core files.
The same code works fine on the local machine, but please tell me if it's just my computer and you can't see what my problem is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That sounds suspiciously like the cache under Global Settings...try that...I have experienced that problem before, under the Admin back-end, the menus wouldn't work..then again, I got best results under Opera, in Chrome it doesn't work properly...weird...

Comment: thanks it was the cache, however this means I can't use cache at all? i need it for the events and RSS feeds...

Comment: Once you've made the changes you can turn the cache back on. If you make a "live" change then it will take a short time to appear on the site.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cache is the most likely culprit as tommieb says.

Alternatively, it could be a CSS issue, since you're using sprites. You don't say what you're changing in the menu, but for example if you change a menu item title from "Sports" to something else, it will still say "Sports" because the text is part of the image.